# I was trying to copy some css and layout to make a copy of telerick TreeView, confused by an attribute or few

Tags: jquery, css, telerik

The Telerick Control "TreeView" does not have the functionality I want, so i am making my own version of it.  Since my customers use the TreeView already by then, it makes sense to make it look the same or similar.

I was looking through the css for it, and applied it where it should be, but it is not taking grasp.  I was curious if the following attributes were legitimate css of if they were added for the Telerick control.

```
.RadTreeView
{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Since Telerick relies on a backend, I am making an AJAX version that does the same thing, but without the required dependancies of a defined backend.  That way, I can do something like make a TreeView Widget of sorts which can just be placed into code whereever and passed the parameters to do what is needed.

The tree works perfectly, and i added all of the noted classes.  Why doesnt it look like the way it should?

Also:  Yes, i checked references, it recognized the CSS but doesnt do all the fanciness with it.

Here is a fiddle to give you my workspace BUT it doesnt have proper indenting in the fiddle for the UL and LI: http://jsfiddle.net/fallenreaper/YQuw6/

Comment: I was just told by a coworker that the -webkit-touch-callout is a legitimate css attribute.  Never the less, why is my code not rendering correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are "legitimate", they're webkit specific though.
More info on [-webkit-touch-callout](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-touch-callout) and [-webkit-tap-highlight-color](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-tap-highlight-color).

I'm not sure exactly what you want but if you just want to indent child items in the tree, something as simple as the following will do:

```
ul > li {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YQuw6/4/)